# Is re-entering Laos a second time within 30 days on visa exemption with Scandinavian passport allowed?

Tags: visa-free-entry, laos, visa-runs, swedish-citizens

In 2018, holders of Scandinavian passports can visit Laos for 15 days without a need for visa.

I have already visited once with no problem but I was wondering if I can go back again to Laos sooner than 30 days after I left and get another visa exemption for 15 days or if there is a cutoff time?

Answers from people who have actually done this or attempted to do it are especially welcome.

I have a Swedish passport.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not first hand information but one of my colleagues successfully went back 2 times in 2 weeks in the summer of 2019.

However when I verified with a second friend, who tried a similar return 26 days after departing he was denied his second entry.

Both were Swedish passport holders so it seems to be a little ad hoc or the rules are changing rapidly.

I am going myself in March so it depends how quick you need the exact first hand information but I am scheduled for 2 entries within 3 weeks

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica lol using iPad onboard an 350 aircraft in turbulent weather hahahaha